# Spinner android and okhttp3, When I have fetched data it's no displays in spinner only when I am clicking spinner

Tags: android, spinner, okhttp

I'm using the okhttp3 to fetch data and it then this data are displaying in spinner. But it's not happend. The spinner as empty but when I drop down the spinner I can see my date fetched by okhttp3. I'm not pretty sure why spinner is empty at the beginning.

```
    private List<String> categories;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("MESSAGE_LOGIN");

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(message);

        categories = new ArrayList<String>();

        Log.d("LOGIN", "TEST!!!");
        final Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.add("type","category");

        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"), params.toString());
        categories = postRequest(MainActivity.postURIStage, body);

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

        // Drop down layout style - list view
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        // Spinner click listener
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // On selecting a spinner item
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        // Showing selected spinner item
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public List<String> postRequest(String postUrl, RequestBody postBody) {
        final List<String> categories1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(postUrl)
                .post(postBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                // Cancel the post on failure.
                call.cancel();
                Log.d("FAIL", e.getMessage());
                // In order to access the TextView inside the UI thread, the code is executed inside runOnUiThread()
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView responseTextLogin = findViewById(R.id.responseTextLogin);
                        responseTextLogin.setText("Server is unreachable. Please try soon.");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                // In order to access the TextView inside the UI thread, the code is executed inside runOnUiThread()
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView responseTextLogin = findViewById(R.id.textView);
                        try {
                            String categoryResponseString = response.body().string();
                            Log.d("TEST:", categoryResponseString);

                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(categoryResponseString);
                            Log.d("Message", "Message form the server : " + jsonResponse.getJSONArray("message"));
                                try {
                                    // Parse categories from api.php
                                    JSONArray categoriesArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("message");
                                    // Lopping through all categories
                                    for (int i = 0; i < categoriesArray.length(); i++) {
                                        JSONObject c = categoriesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                        String name = c.getString("name");
                                        categories1.add(name);
                                    }
                                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                                    Log.e("TAG", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                                }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            responseTextLogin.setText("No categories as active state in DB!");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return categories1;

    }
}
```

Even though I'll select data in the spinner no reaction for this setOnItemSelectedListener function

```
Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I have attached photos that can be seen empty spinner and when I'll click it show data but it no show at the beginning.

[Empty spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucvYk.png)

[When I clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biaOL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the way your code is written, the spinner populates with the empty categories ArrayList before the results are returned.

You can move the Spinner population into the onResponse of the postRequest method

```
public List<String> postRequest(String postUrl, RequestBody postBody) {
        final List<String> categories1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(postUrl)
                .post(postBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                // Cancel the post on failure.
                call.cancel();
                Log.d("FAIL", e.getMessage());
                // In order to access the TextView inside the UI thread, the code is executed inside runOnUiThread()
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView responseTextLogin = findViewById(R.id.responseTextLogin);
                        responseTextLogin.setText("Server is unreachable. Please try soon.");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                // In order to access the TextView inside the UI thread, the code is executed inside runOnUiThread()
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView responseTextLogin = findViewById(R.id.textView);
                        try {
                            String categoryResponseString = response.body().string();
                            Log.d("TEST:", categoryResponseString);

                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(categoryResponseString);
                            Log.d("Message", "Message form the server : " + jsonResponse.getJSONArray("message"));
                            try {
                                // Parse categories from api.php
                                JSONArray categoriesArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("message");
                                // Lopping through all categories
                                for (int i = 0; i < categoriesArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject c = categoriesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String name = c.getString("name");
                                    categories1.add(name);
                                }

                                // Creating adapter for spinner
                                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

                                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                                // Attaching data adapter to spinner
                                spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                                // Spinner click listener
                                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
                            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                                Log.e("TAG", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            responseTextLogin.setText("No categories as active state in DB!");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return categories1;

    }
```

Or you can put your code in a thread and get results on UI thread before populating the Spinner

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                categories = postRequest(MainActivity.postURIStage, body);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Creating adapter for spinner
                        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

                        // Drop down layout style - list view
                        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        // Attaching data adapter to spinner
                        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                        // Spinner click listener
                        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: Thanks Lisa. The first a solution has worked. But although had to change **this** on to **activitName.this** because it also caused error in my code as well. Thank so much